# Proper way to create PHP prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to PHP

Currently working on building my 1st web app!

I created this PHP script for registering / signing up for my web app, 
and I want it to prevent SQL injection
So I need some guideance here, I learned all by my self from ground zero!

So I decided to use from what I have read and learned.

**Here's my code:**

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$selected_db = "User";
$selected_table = "usersbio";

// Create connection
$linking = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $selected_db);

// Input variable
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['lastname']);
$userpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userpass']);
$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['useremail']);
$udob_d = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdobd']);
$udob_m = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdobm']);
$udob_y = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdoby']);

$hashingpass = password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Saving data to db - table
$stmt = $linking->prepare("INSERT INTO $selected_table (userfirstname, 
userlastname, userpasskey, useremail, userdobd, userdobm, userdoby) 
VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");

$stmt->bind_param('s', 's', 's', 's', 'i', 's', 'i', $firstname, 
$lastname, $hashingpass, $useremail, $udob_d, $udob_m, $udob_y);
$stmt->execute();

$linking->close();
```

Comment: Please post your code in here, not as link to an external image.

Comment: Don't rely on the `real_escape_string()` functions to prevent SQL injection, [they alone are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: I still don't know how to post the code

Comment: After that open a `bind_param` manual.

Comment: The [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is wrong. The types should be in _one_ string as first param: 'ssiss...'.

Comment: wait, let me try to add the text code

Comment: @jeff, that is the thing I don't know

this 'ssiss' thing really confuse me

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto Did you click the link in Jeff's comment? Look for the examples and compare it to yours.

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto just paste the code in there and I can format it for you!

Comment: let me try, sry real newbie here (T_T)

Comment: done, code is in now

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use PDO instead. Mysqli is just there to make code more long-winded.

Comment: You already use prepared statements, in this case you should **not** call `real_escape_string()` beforehand. There is no need to escape anything, because the database gets the SQL statement and the user input separately and does not have to extract the user input from the SQL statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You `prepare()` statement looks like it should work...

Also as Alex Howansky said:

Don't rely on the real_escape_string() functions to prevent SQL injection, they alone are not sufficient. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either mysqli or PDO. This post has some good examples.

Refer to: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

**You also have to remove the the single quotes around the question marks...**

**TRY THIS:**

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$selected_db = "User";
$selected_table = "usersbio";

// Create connection
$linking = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $selected_db);

// Input variable
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['lastname']);
$userpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userpass']);
$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['useremail']);
$udob_d = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdobd']);
$udob_m = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdobm']);
$udob_y = mysqli_real_escape_string($linking, $_POST['userdoby']);

$hashingpass = password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Saving data to db - table
$stmt = $linking->prepare("INSERT INTO $selected_table (userfirstname, 
userlastname, userpasskey, useremail, userdobd, userdobm, userdoby) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $firstname, 
$lastname, $hashingpass, $useremail, $udob_d, $udob_m, $udob_y);
$stmt->execute();

$linking->close();
```

**THIS IS THE UPDATED QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO $selected_table (userfirstname, userlastname, userpasskey, useremail, userdobd, userdobm, userdoby)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

If you need more help with prepared statements take a look at this link:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Yes I read that, because of that I decided to use prepared statement

Comment: let me try, a moment please

Comment: I change 's', 's', 's', 's', 'i', 's', 'i' to 'ssssisi'
And I got this error :
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto go ahead and try again I have updated my answer

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto can  you accept there is a check right under where the downvotes and upvotes you click that and that is how you accept!

Comment: done, haha, many thanks to all review this newbie post of mine

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto no problem, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting started, I'd suggest using PDO instead of the old mysqli interface. It's much less verbose and easier to use. Here's how your code would look:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$selected_db = "User";

// Create connection
$linking = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$selected_db", $user, $pass);

// Saving data to db - table
$query = "
    INSERT INTO usersbio
    (userfirstname, userlastname, userpasskey, useremail, userdobd, userdobm, userdoby)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$params = [
    $_POST["firstname"],
    $_POST["lastname"],
    password_hash($_POST["userpass"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
    $_POST["useremail"],
    $_POST["userdobd"],
    $_POST["userdobm"],
    $_POST["userdoby"],
];
$stmt = $linking->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

$linking->close();
```